# How do I make a sprite full of different images (hover, non-hover, etc)?

Tags: css, images, graphics, dynamic

I understand there are tools on the net to make a sprite, but I'd like to learn how to create icons for the different states of the icon.  Is there an easy way to make all these different variations of this icon:

[image]

(Also, can you tell me how I can better word my question so it doesn't sound like I'm asking for sprite advice?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, and you already know that a sprite is really just an image-combining-image, then the last part you need to know is about the CSS.

The CSS is what associates a portion of your image with a state.  You create the html representing the button, assign it a class, then you write up your CSS.

```
.my-button{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:url('my-button-sprite.gif') top left no-repeat;
}
.my-button:hover{background-position: 20px 0px;}
```

Just add an appropriate horizontal offset (the first number) to bump the sprite where it should appear for the desired state.

Comment: Virtuosi Media is right, sprites can be used for more than just button states.  One one of my sites I have a sprite that combines all of my buttons, bullets, icons AND horizontal repeat images.  My CSS is pretty clean, assigning the background to 30+ elements at once, then only adjusting the offsets for each.  This dramatically cut down the number of requests and page load time.

Answer (score 0):

Hover images aren't the only use for a CSS sprite, you can also use a sprite for static images  or different icon states. You would create a single image pretty much like you have given as an example and use different CSS background coordinates for each icon state. The trick is just getting the background coordinates right.